# Upload new file to the model filefield

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I have a **model** for Video:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    original_video = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    mp4_720 = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name,blank=True, null=True)
    converted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And this is the **views.py**:

```
def upload_video(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            video = form.save(commit=False)
            video.save()
            convert_video.delay(video.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Lastly the **tasks.py**:

```
def get_upload_file_name(video):
    name = video.title
    name = name+'.mp4'
    return name

from pyvid.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
@app.task
def convert_video(video_id):
    video = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
    video_path = str(MEDIA_ROOT)+'/'+str(video.original_video)
    convert_video_name = get_upload_file_name(video)
    cmd = 'ffmpeg -i %s -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart %s.mp4' % (video_path, convert_video_name)
    subprocess.call(
        cmd,
        shell=True
    )
    video.mp4_720 = convert_video_name
    video.converted = True
    video.save()
```

The problem is, even though `video.mp4_720` is to upload by the `upload_to=get_upload_file_name()`, its just taking the value of convert_video_name file path (which is the converted video and is in the base directory of the project) but not uploading the new file to the path specified.

How do I upload the new converted file in to the filefield of `mp4_720` with the uploaded path?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1.`upload_to` save image relative to your `MEDIA_ROOT` ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)). 
And this work only if you're uploading file using form but here, you are manually setting `video.mp4_720`.

2.While converting video, you should save output in MEDIA_ROOT (you should provide absolute url ) but you are just providing file name,
Modify your code:

```
video_path = str(MEDIA_ROOT)+'/'+str(video.original_video)
convert_video_name = get_upload_file_name(video)
output_path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + convert_video_name
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i %s -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart %s.mp4' % (video_path, output_path)
```

3. If you are manually setting FileField, you should provide file path relating to your `MEDIA_ROOT`. Now your code should work as in statement `video.mp4_720 = convert_video_name` is already relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`.

I hope this will solve your problem. I have to tested the code.